# Binary 12 is 1100 but signed 4 is also 1100. Can someone please explain how this works?

Tags: binary, twos-complement

i know that we represent negative number by using 2's complement but some of the binary value that we get after 2's complement are having the same binary number. so, how do this works?

Answer (score 0):

To compute 2's complement, it is necessary to know the total number of binary digits. If you use 4 binary digits, then -4 = 1100, but if you use 5 binary digits, then -4 = 11100.

Now, in the case of 4 binary digits, only the numbers -8 up to 7 can be represented. So, 1100 represents -4, not 12.

In the case of 5 binary digits, however, (0)1100 represents 12, not -4.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot represent the value 12 in 4 bits **signed**.

Your representation range in 4 bit signed is [-8, +7].

In binary, you have to specify what type is the bits you are looking, since it is not the same if signed or unsigned.

The binary "1100":

- In 4 bit signed represents -4
- In 4 bit unsigned represents 12

You can represent 12 in 4 bit **unsigned**, because this representation does not have negative numbers, thus it does not need a sign bit, allowing it to use all the bits for value, resulting in the range [0, +15].

To represent 12 in binary signed, you would need 5 bits: 01100